# Scipy bandpass filter returns infinite or nan values

Tags: python, scipy, bandpass-filter

I want to implement a bandpass filter to retrieve all values with a frequency between 150 kHz and 500 kHz. The sampling rate is 1 MHz. Since the function butter from scipy doesn't allow 500 kHz, I replaced it by 499.999 kHz.
The input is a pandas.Series with 2.388 million entries. There are no nan values.

```
print(series)
Out:
0          0.354182
1          0.345122
2          0.361368
3          0.353870
4          0.351058

2387995    0.362617
2387996    0.363867
2387997    0.374490
2387998    0.375739
2387999    0.362617
Name: Input, Length: 2388000, dtype: float64
```

[image: Input Series]

Here is the code:

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq

    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

fs = 1000000.0
lowcut = 150000.0
highcut = 499999.0

y = butter_bandpass_filter(series.values, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=6)
```

The values of y grow exponentially until the are infinite (after 477350 values) and afterwards they are only nan.

```
print(y)
Out:
[ 0.05232346 -0.13843946  0.05059037 ...         nan         nan
         nan]

print(y[477340:477356])
Out:
[ 4.89094265e+307 -4.89827252e+307  4.90561347e+307 -4.91296550e+307
  4.92032864e+307 -4.92770291e+307  4.93508831e+307 -4.94248488e+307
  4.94989261e+307 -4.95731154e+307             -inf              inf
              nan              nan              nan              nan]
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *"...  retrieve all values with a frequency between 150 kHz and 500 kHz. The sampling rate is 1 MHz."*  FYI: 500 kHz is the Nyquist frequency, so there are no frequencies above 500 kHz in your sample.  I think you actually want a high-pass filter with cutoff 150 kHz.

Comment: *"Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?"* The requested transition width of just 1 Hz for the upper end of your bandpass filter is probably demanding too much from a filter of order 6.  It looks like `butter` is creating an unstable filter.  Try using a high-pass filter (see my previous comment).  Also, generally the SOS format for a filter has better numerical properties; try adding `output='sos'` to the call of `butter`, and change from using `lfilter` to [`sosfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html).

Comment: You are right. Choosing 499000 instead of 499999 for highcut solved it. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Does the use of a butter high-pass filter for 150 kHz simultanously ensures the Nyquist criteria, so that frequencies above 500 kHz (sampling rate 1 MHz) are removed as well?

Comment: You have a discrete time signal sampled at 1 MHz.  There are no frequencies in that signal above the Nyquist frequency of 500 kHz.  (If the signal is a sample of an analog signal, and if the analog signal had frequencies above 500 kHz, you would have had to apply an analog lowpass or bandpass filter to the analog signal with an upper cutoff of 500 kHz before sampling at 1 MHz to avoid [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).)